# python - can i name my file as logging.py

Tags: python, import

So I want to have a logging wrapper file - which is in a directory like this :

```
| team
 -- | libraries
    --  | logging.py
    --  | __init__.py
```

Problem is that inside logging I do :

```
from logging import ....
```

which is the native Python logging mechanism. So when writing tests for my logging wrapper, or when importing that in other places like `import team.libraries.logging`

the above line fails because I think it tries to import from the local logging file.

So my question is :

Would it be best to change the order in which python tries to import? i.e. first try on where the python is installed etc? Is it good practise?

Or better to just change my local file name?

PS : I will rename the file since it's easier, but still - is there a way to do so? is it possible at all?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and just rename the file.

Comment: does this line work: "import team.libraries.logging" ? If yes, you can try: `from .logging import` (the dot)

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding collisions with built-in modules.

Comment: The obvious answer is no, it's not good practice to mess around with import for no good reason, and yes, it's best to just change your local file name. But frankly I'm curious if it's even possible to do what you want, so I'm hoping someone pops in soon with the ill-advised answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be best to change the order in which python tries to import? i.e. first try on where the python is installed etc? Is it good practise?

No. Clearly not.

> Or better to just change my local file name?

Yes, for sure.

All reasons are already explained in comments and are pretty obvious.